# Iterating over itemControllers init function

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm iterating over itemControllers init functions verifying a specific condition. What should I do if I want to stop iterating when the condition has changed? By iterating, I mean going over every single itemController inits function. Example :

```
init: function(){

    if(getCurrentConvId()){ 
        var self = this;

        if(self.get('model').id == getCurrentConvId()){
            self.get('controllers.conversation').set('selectedConv', this.get('model'));
            self.send('clickConv', self.get('model'));

            **Here I would like to stop iterating because conv has been found**
        }           
    }   
},
```

An idea I had was to put an observer on a convFound property in the ArrayController but the problem is that the code on init functions will be executed before the observer is even part of the app. Any suggestions?

Comment: how will that second `if` statement ever execute if there is a return above it? ...also i do not see any iterating going on?

Comment: Well because each itemController as an init function, they're all gonna be executed one after another, which I called 'iterating'. It isn't a real iteration but it kind of is in a certain way. Even if I use 'return', it is gonna step out of the current itemController init's function but isn't gonna stop following itemController init's function. Can add more details if you ask.

Comment: I'm saying that putting the return in that first `if` is going to stop the execution of every `init()` that resolves true.  the second `if` block would never execute on any of the controllers

Comment: I removed the return that wasn't intended my bad.